# Internal Error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, internal

I'm trying to launch a program in Eclipse, but I keep getting an error message saying:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching WindChillTester".
org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel**
```

WindChillTester is the name of my program. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Try `-clean`ing Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU
```

...at the end of eclipse.ini seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: I find this to be a strange, unrelated solution, but I admit it solved the problem for me too. I was trying to run a junit test on Luna on Ubuntu.